# How to remove aliased lines with anti-aliasing?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, optimization, antialiasing

I rendered my image with Eevee (256 samples, resolution - 1920 x 1080) and this is what I've got:

[image]

There are ugly, sharp edges on my rendered image (these ones I highlighted).
Also, in the upper part, I marked with the red circle section that got "pixelated" but this is another thing.

Is there anything I can do in order to smooth these edges ? Or do I have to increase the number of samples ?

I'm an absolute beginner with Blender and the topic of "optimization" sounds like magic to me.

Comment: The technical term would be *How to remove aliased lines with anti-aliasing?*

Comment: Have you accidentally rendered it while in Edit (not Object) mode?

Comment: Nope, I rendered it while in Object mode, that's for sure.

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file?